# How to insert json object in mysql database using node

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I am getting error to post json object into mysql database....

```
app.post('/subscriptions', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
      connection.connect(function(err) {
        var insert_subscription = `INSERT INTO subscription VALUES ('${req.body}')`
        connection.query(insert_subscription, function (err, result) {  
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
        });
    });
});
```

in app.post I have used jsonparser so i am getting json type of req body data like

```
{
  "keys": {
           "auth": "BPWFls4u5Ytu-ht7sH6U", 
           "p256dh": "BPWFls4u5Ytu-ht7sH6U"
          }, 
  "endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com-8ud8c0hwjejk4_21LKoAtl8NWOJpKkUA03l4EAAZhqQQ3C", 
  "expirationTime": null
}
```

but i'm getting this type of error =>  INSERT INTO subscription VALUES ('[object Object]')

mysql database structure is

```
+--------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| subscription | json | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

what i was expected in database record => data store as single json object

**When i user this type of query =>**

```
var subscription = req.body;
var insert_subscription = `INSERT INTO subscription VALUES ('
        {
           "endpoint": "${subscription.endpoint}", 
           "expirationTime": "${subscription.expirationTime}", 
              "keys": {
                 "p256dh": "${subscription.keys.p256dh}", 
                  "auth": "${subscription.keys.auth}"
             }
          }
      ')`
```

**It's works but i wan't to send data as an object like
var insert_subscription = `INSERT INTO subscription VALUES ('${req.body}')`**

Comment: Provide precise and complete error message. PS. I see that the literal of the query text in your code (assigning into `insert_subscription`) is wrapped with backticks, and the statement is not finalized with `;` - is this correct?

Comment: @Akina yes it's correct.......

Comment: I think that `${req.body}` which is an object (it seems that error message tells about this) must be converted to string... investigate the value of `insert_subscription` after assigning.